# magento 2.4.5 admin product edit weight-handler

Tags: javascript, admin, magento2.4

In magento 2.4.5, I'm trying to add a custom js script to a field (adding character counter to meta description field).

To complete such task I've noticed that a js script is already attached to weight field, that is Magento_Catalog/js/product/weight-handler.js, to manage situations such as a product has weight or is weightless.

I'd want to create a script similar to the above one, but I don't understand how and where such script is called. Even if I add any console.debug line and compile and clear cache, I can't manage to see such script in action.

Could anyone give me a hint on how weight-handler script ios working? Thank you.